# recibir variables desde node js en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Quiero leer una variable del servidor en mi `HTML` estoy utilizando `nodejs`, `JS` y `HTML`

Así la envío pero no se como cacharla en el `JS` para pintarla en el `HTML`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app); 
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path    = require("path");
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send();
});
http.listen(3030,()=>{
  console.log('Server running on port 3030');
});
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/chat.html'),{user:req.body.user});
  console.log(req.body.user)
})
```

Quiero cacharla aqui

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(user)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas sencilla es usando jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/",
      method:"post",
      success: function( user ) {
        console.log(user"
      }
    });
```

Recuerda que debes importar la libreria para usar ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, creo que lo primero que debes hacer es [entender como funcionan las peticiones entre cliente y servidor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yfxKZWvN8k).

Cuando logres comprender bien el tema sabrás que para poder obtener información de un servidor (nodejs en este caso) desde tu `index.html` debes enviar una petición HTTP mediante javascript y procesar la respuesta asíncrona a esa petición.

Como te han indicado en otra respuesta, una opción podría ser usar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) que te ofrece una interfaz bastante fácil de usar con la cual puedes implementar [Ajax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ybgWmSCAu8).

Comment: si pero cuando me logeo me tiene que mandar al html donde quiero leer la variable user pero no se como charla

Comment: como te comentamos, debes hacer una petición HTTP desde javascript para obtener respuestas del servidor. El cliente (es decir, el navegador del usuario) siempre debe iniciar la conexión con el servidor, el servidor simplemente te responde a esas peticiones que le haces desde el cliente, lo que debes hacer es crear un endpoint en tu servidor que retorne la información que necesitas (la variable `user` que mencionas), luego sirves tu archivo HTML el cual debe contener un script que te permite hacer una petición al endpoint que creaste previamente en el servidor.